# Remove special chars from string except the whitespaces?

Tags: regex, perl

Hello I am trying to remove numbers and special characters, except the white spaces from the following string:

```
$string = 'ClA�\u0083A�A�ment Lecigne';
```

Using the following code:

```
$string =~ tr/a-zA-Z//dc;
```

We obtain the following:

```
"ClAuAAmentLecigne"
```

What I really need is this:

```
"ClAuAAment Lecigne"
```

Can someone assist me improving the code? Thanks,

Comment: what `\u0083` represents? its a single character.  why `u` is added in expected output?

Comment: You are replacing everything except `a-zA-Z` with nothing, why do you expect to see a space? Also, you should be seeing `ClAAAmentLecigne` not `ClAuAAmentLecigne`.

Comment: @Braj The \u0083 this has to do with chars ASCII and UTF8 conversions. I don't know what does it mean. However I can say that this \u0083 might represent an accent.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen as I said it keeps all the characters and replace all special chars and numbers.

Comment: @SamuelDonadelli It removes the complement of `a-zA-Z` which is everything *but* `a-zA-Z`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's quite a few whitespace characters.

```
$ unichars '\s'
 ---- U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION
 ---- U+000A LINE FEED
 ---- U+000B LINE TABULATION
 ---- U+000C FORM FEED
 ---- U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN
 ---- U+0020 SPACE
 ---- U+0085 NEXT LINE
 ---- U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
 ---- U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
 ---- U+2000 EN QUAD
 ---- U+2001 EM QUAD
 ---- U+2002 EN SPACE
 ---- U+2003 EM SPACE
 ---- U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
 ---- U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
 ---- U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
 ---- U+2007 FIGURE SPACE
 ---- U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
 ---- U+2009 THIN SPACE
 ---- U+200A HAIR SPACE
 ---- U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR
 ---- U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
 ---- U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
 ---- U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
 ---- U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

If you wanted to keep using `tr///`, you'd have to list them all

```
$string =~ tr/a-zA-Z\x09\x0A\x0B...\x{3000}//dc;
```

It's simpler to switch to `s///`.

```
$string =~ s/[^\pL\s]//g;   # Remove all but letters and whitespace
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a space in `tr/a-zA-Z //dc;`

```
$string = 'ClA�\u0083A�A�ment Lecigne';
$string =~ tr/a-zA-Z //dc;
print $string . "\n";
```

Output:

```
ClAuAAment Lecigne
```

Comment: where is `u` in the output :) As OP looks for `ClAuAAment Lecigne`

Comment: @braj, for me, I think perl is interpreting `\u0083` as another character. I don't get the `u` when running op's code either. I figure if he sees the `u`, it would still work for him. Maybe different version of perl?

Comment: @Braj, The missing `u` is because the OP and Matt meant to use `$string = '...';` instead of `$string = "...";`

Comment: The OP asked to keep whitespace, but you strip out quite a lot of it. It returns "abcdef" for "abc def" (that's a tab).

Comment: Thanks @ikegami, if OP needs a tab he can add `\t` to the `tr` as well. His example only included a space so I figured I'd start there.